# Spring: problem with setter Dependence Injection

Tags: java-ee-6, spring-3

I have the following situation:
[image]

I set the beans (in applicationContext.xml) as follows:

```
...
<bean id="bDaoImpl" class="BDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="injBInA" class="ADaoImpl">
   <property name="b" ref="bDaoImpl"/>
</bean>
...
```

Why when I use "b" in the value of the Object class ADaoImpl is null?

Comment: I have the solution. Sorry. Basically when I load the bean from application context (ApplicationContext.getBean) does not load the bean with id = "injBInA" therefore right was never carried out the injection.

Comment: Would be nice if you could mark the question as "answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution. Sorry. Basically when I load the bean from application context (ApplicationContext.getBean) does not load the bean with id = "injBInA" therefore right was never carried out the injection